# Como unificar o valor de uma coluna fazendo um group by de duas colunas diferentes?

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando fazer uma query que precisa trazer o percentual do mes de cada linha para isso eu fiz a query abaixo:

```
 SELECT 
    linhas, 
    month(date) as `data`, 
    round((`M3.0`*0.3),2) + round((Produtividade*0.2),2) + round((qualidade*0.3),2) + round((Produtividade*0.2),2) as soma,
    case when month(date) in ('4','5','6') then 'Quartil 1' 
    when month(date) in ('7','8','9') then 'Quartil 2' 
    when month(date) in ('10','11','12') then 'Quartil 3' 
    else 'Quartil 4' end as quartil
FROM
    nossa_performance.performance_all
WHERE
    MONTH(date) IN ('1','2','3')
GROUP BY linhas,MONTH(date) order by linhas;
```

o retorno da query vem

```
linhas  |  mes   |  percentual
  1         01        80%
  1         02        95%
  1         03        83%
  2         01        55%
  2         02        67%
  2         03        93% ...
```

e eu gostaria de unir as linhas e somar os percentuais tentei um subquery não deu certo:
select line, soma, quartil from

```
( SELECT 
    linhas as line, 
    date as `data`, 
     round((`M3.0`*0.3),2) + round((Produtividade*0.2),2) + round((qualidade*0.3),2) + round((Produtividade*0.2),2) as soma,
    case when month(date) in ('4','5','6') then 'Quartil 1' 
    when month(date) in ('7','8','9') then 'Quartil 2' 
    when month(date) in ('10','11','12') then 'Quartil 3' 
    else 'Quartil 4' end as quartil
FROM
    nossa_performance.performance_all
WHERE
    MONTH(date) IN ('1','2','3')
GROUP BY linhas order by linhas) a group by MONTH(`data`),line;
```

Comment: tentar entender, você tem duas colunas, ColA=10 ColB=20 você quer fazer um calculo dessas duas colunas é isso ?

Comment: eu quero pegar a soma dos percentuais da linha que esta duplicando, tipo no exemplo acima na linha um trazer:   a linha so um vez em vez de duplicar e somar os percentuais na linha somar 80 + 95 + 85